# Guess (or upper bound) the general formula for a double sequence

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, sequences-and-series, enumerative-combinatorics, integer-sequences

Let $t,s \geq 0$ be integers. We have the following recursive formula:
$$f(t+1,s) = f(t,s) + f(t,s-1) + \sum_{0\leq a,b,c \leq h(t):\\a+b+c = s-1}f(t,a)f(t,b)f(t,c),$$ where
$$h(t) = \frac{1}{2}3^t -\frac{1}{2}.$$

The boundary conditions are given by $f(t,0) = 1$ for all $t \geq 0$ and $f(0,s) = 0$ for all $s \geq 1$.

It is not hard to see that 
$$
f(t,1) = 2t
$$
and 
$$
f(t,2) = 4t(t-1).
$$

I wonder what is the general formula for $f(t,s)$. It this is difficult to obtain, then what is a good upper bound for $f(t,s)$?

Comment: I believe $f=2 t, 4 (t-1) t, \frac{2}{3} (t-1) t (14 t-19), \frac{2}{3} (t-1) t (5 t-9) (7 t-8),\frac{2}{15} (t-2) (t-1) t (t (452 t-1229)+739), \dots$ There seems to be a pattern...

Comment: If I understand the OP's question correctly, the condition on $h(t)$ prevents the result to be a polynomial for all $t$: it seems to me that $f(t,3)=0$ for $t=0,1$ and for $t\ge2$, $$f(t,3)=\frac{2}{3}(t-1)t(14t-19)-12=\frac{2}{3}(t-2)(14t^2-5t+9)$$

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform How do you get the result for the last 2? Is there any quick method?

Comment: @HenriCohen You're right. The restriction on $h(t)$ sets an upper limit of the order of the polynomial. Btw, I think f(2,3) should be 12.

Comment: @Wuchen I wrote a short Mathematica script. The computation of $f(t,5)$ took a few minutes. I tried $f(t,6)$ but aborted the computation after five minutes because I have other things to do with MMA.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thank you! I hope someone could address this question. It seems that $f(t,s)\lesssim s! t^s$...

Answer (score 2):

First notice that $h(t)\geq t$ and $h(t+1)=3h(t)+1$ for all $t\geq 0$. Now, for $s>h(t+1)$, the recurrent formula reduces to
$$f(t+1,s) = f(t,s) + f(t,s-1),$$
which further implies that for all $t\geq 0$ and $s>h(t)$ we have $f(t,s) = 0$.

It follows that the restriction $a,b,c\leq h(t)$ in the recurrent formula is inessential and can be dropped. The simplified formula implies a recurrent formula for the generating function:
$$F_t(x) := \sum_{s=0}^{\infty} f(t,s)x^s.$$
Namely, we have $F_0(x) = 1$, and for $t\geq 0$ 
$$F_{t+1}(x) = (1+x)F_t(x) + xF_t(x)^3.$$

In particular,
$$F_1(x) = (1+x)1+x1^3=1+2x,$$
$$F_2(x) = (1+x)(1+2x) + x(1+2x)^3 = 1+  4x+   8x^2+   12x^3+     8x^4,$$
etc.

**UPDATED**. I doubt there is a simple formula for $F_t(x)$, although we can get those for some particular values of $x$ such as
$$F_t(0) = 1,$$
$$F_t(-1) = (-1)^{t},$$
and
\begin{split}
F_t(2) &= \sqrt{2} \sinh(3^t\mathrm{arcsinh}(1/\sqrt{2}))\\
& = \frac{1+\sqrt{3}}2 \alpha^{h(t)} + \frac{1-\sqrt{3}}2 \alpha^{-h(t)},
\end{split}
where $\alpha:=2+\sqrt{3}\approx 3.732$. The values $F_t(2)$ are given by the sequence [A238799](https://oeis.org/A238799) in the OEIS.

From the last formula it follows that $f(t,s)< \frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2^{s+1}} \alpha^{h(t)}$.

Comment: Is there any relationship between this and the Catalan number for the Ternary trees?

Comment: @Wuchen: I do not know what is "Catalan number for the Ternary trees".

Comment: I'm referring to the first answer on this webpage https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238754/n-ary-trees-with-k-internal-nodes-catalan-numbers, which is a generalization of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number. Thank you!